# based on radio button selection redirect to another page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

**I have 2 radio buttons(button 1, button 2), whenever I selected button 1 and click on next button it will redirect to another page same like whenever I select button 2 I click on next button it will redirect to another page .how it *possible.

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3>Add Credential</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-header text-center">
    <h3>Select a cloud provider</h3>
    <h2 class="text-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <div>
      <img src="\src\img\amazon.png">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="amazon" (click)="myRouterLink='/credentials/amzonradi1'" value="IAM Role (Preferred)"  [checked]='true'
           > IAM Role (Preferred)
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="amazon" value=" IAM User " (click)="myRouterLink='/credentials/amzonradi2'"> IAM User
        </label>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

After select radio button and click on the next button it will redirect to another page.

Comment: Please add code whatever you have done so far

Comment: Please add your code ,whatever you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve doing for example, the following:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="[myrouterLink]" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
......

<input type="radio" name="amazon" (click)="myRouterLink='/role'" value="IAM Role 
(Preferred)" (click)="setradio('IAM Role (Preferred)')" [checked]='true'> 
....

<input type="radio" (click)="myRouterLink='/user'" name="amazon" value=" IAM User " 
(click)="setradio(' IAM User ')" ngModel>
```

**Class:**

```
  myrouterLink='/role'
```

[DEMO](http://%20stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gc1fit?file=app%2Fapp.component.%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bts)

Comment: Leave <button type="button" [routerLink]="[myrouterLink]" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button> so it will redirect to whereever myRouterLink has the value. Eventually, set in the class the default value to '/credentials/amzonradi1'

Comment: Can you update the question post with the latest code please?

Comment: You didn't put the code for the button. Is it because you are getting an error about the router ?

Comment: Look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gc1fit?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: So it's fixed? great! :)